# History refresh of materialized view

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

i have a simple materialized view (on oracle 11g):

```
  CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "MV_TEST" 
  TABLESPACE "DATA"   
  REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
  WITH PRIMARY KEY USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT
  USING ENFORCED CONSTRAINTS DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
  AS 
  SELECT
    1,2,3  
  FROM
    TABLE_1@dblink;
```

and i refresh it with this:

```
 begin      

      DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(MV_TEST, 'FAST', '', TRUE, FALSE, 0,0,0,FALSE, FALSE);
 end;
```

How i can see an history of refresh operation like this?

```
1-dic-2015 10:34 fast
1-dic-2015 10:50 fast
1-dic-2015 10:55 fast
1-dic-2015 11:05 fast
1-dic-2015 11:30 fast
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use this :

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES where last_refresh between '29-OCT-10' AND '31-OCT-10';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES where last_refresh > '28-OCT-10';
```